# Angular testing: tick cannot advance the time from timers outside its own fakeAsync zone

Tags: angular, testing

All the examples I have found so far with `tick()`  are related to the timer being in the same `fakeAsync`.

Consider you have some kind of initialization that involves `setTimeout` and you'd like to put it in `beforeEach()` and advance the clock in the `it()`. I cannot do it using angular only :(

Please take a look at the examples below. For simplicity the "initialization" consists of a simple `setTiemout`.
Any advice or deeper explanations on the `tick` misbehavior and if there is a way to overcome it will be much appreciated.

This one always fails, cannot advance the time at all:

```
describe("counter1", () => {
        let counter = 0;
        beforeEach(() => {
            setTimeout(()=> ++counter, 10);
        });
        it("is incremented", fakeAsync(() => {
            expect(counter).toBe(0); // TRUE
            tick(50);
            expect(counter).toBe(1);  // FALSE; tick() can not advance the timer when it is outside the current fakeAsync
        }));
    });
```

This is similar to the one above but in addition, there is `Error: 1 timer(s) still in the queue.` that I cannot get rid of because of the `fakeAsync` in the `beforeEach`

```
    describe("counter1fakeAsync" , () => {
        let counter = 0;
        beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
            setTimeout(()=> ++counter, 10);
        }));
        it("is incremented", fakeAsync(() => {
            expect(counter).toBe(0); // TRUE
            tick(50);
            expect(counter).toBe(1);  // FALSE; tick() can not advance the timer when it is outside the current fakeAsync
            // Even more you cannot get rid of `Error: 1 timer(s) still in the queue.`
        }));
    });
```

This works, all examples on the Ineternet are like this:

```
    describe("counter2",  () => {
        let counter = 0;
        it("is incremented", fakeAsync(() => {
            setTimeout(()=> ++counter, 10);
            expect(counter).toBe(0); // TRUE
            tick(50);
            expect(counter).toBe(1);  // TRUE; tick() can advance the timer if it is in the same fakeAsync
        }));
    });
```

jasmine.clock() also works:

```
    describe("counter3",  () => {
        let counter = 0;
        beforeEach(() => {
            jasmine.clock().uninstall(); // NEEDED :( or try with __zone_symbol__fakeAsyncPatchLock
            jasmine.clock().install();
            setTimeout(()=> ++counter, 10);
        });
        afterEach(() => {
            jasmine.clock().uninstall();
        });
        it("is incremented", () => {
            expect(counter).toBe(0); // TRUE
            jasmine.clock().tick(50);
            expect(counter).toBe(1);  // TRUE; jasmine.clock().tick() just works as expected
        });
    });
```